# Is there a flag for update system in place?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

Lets face it stuff changes. Things become depreciated, ideas on how things are done change. Change is a part of the world. This change can create problems however. Answers no longer become valid. Information on the page may lead to dead end urls.

So I was wondering if answers can be flagged for update? If not I have thought of three ways of doing this (one I find to be better than the other).

The first is upon being flagged the owner of the answer is notified that the question is no longer valid.

The second is you put this back on the "active questions" section. (and possibly notify the owner)

And lastly you could use the review a question system.

Please note: While yes you can in fact edit the question a) not everyone knows the correct answer yet does know the answer is wrong b) not everyone has an account or doesn't want to edit it themselves (especially with long answers that need full blown remakes).

It's easy to tell if a process no longer works. But the problem I see with this system as a  whole is when it comes to troubleshooting.

If this were to be put into place people may flag a question for updating just because it doesn't work for them. Getting the same problems as described in the question / answer isn't always the easiest.

Do you think this would be effective and do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're asking.  Maybe if you provided a specific example of what you mean?  Flagging is probably not the right term; flags are only cast against a post when there is a serious problem that requires moderator attention.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How do you notify people that a answer need to be updated may be a better way of saying this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The best example I remember is one that dealt with what Windows copies were allowed where due to copyright stuffs. The owner of the question was very good at updating it. However had he of not been this could of created problems for future people looking at the question.

Comment: *needs to be updated

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in the current system, at least to some extent.

A comment can notify the answerer that the answer needs fixing. It also warns readers to possible issues with the answer.

Secondly, you can bounty the questions, there is a specific bounty reason for such cases:

> #### Current answers are outdated
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

This bumps the question and puts it into the featured tab. It's also an added incentive for the answerer to fix the answer.

Comment: That's what I was saying with the user no longer being active. Also I don't like using rep on things like that. While you don't care because you don't lose privileges last time I did.

Comment: @Griffin then you can edit the question and say "Update: due to X, some answers are out of date" (to bump it). And the comment still serves as an indicator to others. This is a rare occurrence, I don't see a particular need for a feature, that's all.

Comment: Wouldn't over time that cause the problem of lots of answers? I'd rather answer to get the points from an upvote than edit.

Comment: @Griffin You're talking about questions that have the issue of changing frequently? Such questions are usually off topic.